# xslt - programming techniques

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

A question on Oliver Beckers efficient methods on xslt programming at this [link.](http://www.xml.org//sites/www.xml.org/files/xslt_efficient_programming_techniques.pdf#page=5)

We know that using this code, we can eliminate verbose xsl choose method

```
concat(
substring(Str1,1 div Cond),
substring(Str2,1 div not(Cond))
)
```

However what can we specify in 'condition', just to check for presence or absence of nodes?

we cannot specify

```
concat(
substring(Str1,1 div test="/node"),
substring(Str2,1 div not(test="/node"))
)
```

which will throw syntax errors.

Comment: Cond must be a boolean XPath expression. (test="/node") is a boolean XPath expression, but probably not the one you intended, and it probably fails because you're in a a context where double-quotes aren't allowed. Use boolean(/node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression (where **node** is the name of the node you want to test):

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
   substring('Yes', 1 div not(not(/root/node))), 
   substring('No', 1 div not(/root/node)))"/>
```

Or better still

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
   substring('Yes', 1 div boolean(/root/node)), 
   substring('No', 1 div not(/root/node)))"/>
```

When applied to this XML, then **Yes** is output

```
<root>
   <node>Test</node>
</root>
```

But when applied to this XML, the **No** is output

```
<root>
   <othernode>Test</othernode>
</root>
```

Comment: Good, +1, but it is better to replace `not(not())` with `boolean()`

Comment: Ah yes, that would be better. I have amended my answer to show this. Thanks!