# XSLT set default value when selected one is not available

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to set a default value using `<xsl:value-of>`? I am attempting to produce JSON output with an XSLT stylesheet and certain fields might not be available during the processing stage. This leaves a null value which breaks the validity of the JSON document. Ideally I'd be able to set a default value if one is not available. So in the case of:

```
    "foo_count": <xsl:value-of select="count(foo)" />
```

If `<foo>` is not available in the document, can I just set this to 0 somehow?

Comment: I can only think of <xsl:choose>...

Comment: If **foo** is not present, then `count(foo)` should return 0 anyway...

Comment: Alternatively, you might be interested in a technique called "Becker's Method" which could help you out here. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231385/xslt-programming-techniques

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is either [choose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256169.aspx)

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="foo">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(foo)" />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

or use [if test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256209.aspx)

```
<xsl:if test="foo">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(foo)" />
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(foo)">
  <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

or use a [named template for calling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256487.aspx)

```
<xsl:template name="default">
  <xsl:param name="node"/>
  <xsl:if test="$node">
      <xsl:value-of select="count($node)" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($node)">
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

 <!-- use this in your actual translate -->
 <xsl:call-template name="default">
         <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Okay, that's going to be painful for a huge document, but it does solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose the `xsl:when` version is a little faster than the double if one if you have a huge amount of them and should be used in the template.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I didn't test for performance (cpu nor memory) and that highly depends on the parser used. If performance matter you better run some tests with each approach on a significant set to see which one fits your requirements.

Comment: @rene anyways the advantage of a template is that the implementation can quickly be switched :)

Answer (score 20):

### XSLT/XPath 2

Using [Sequence Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-sequence-expressions):

```
<xsl:value-of select="(foo,0)[1]"/>
```

### Explanation

> One way to construct a sequence is by using the comma operator, which
> **evaluates each of its operands and concatenates the resulting
> sequences**, in order, into a single result sequence.

Comment: I am not the author of the given "explanation" and it is not correct. The comma operator simply evaluates a sequence of items from the given expression. There is no concatenation going on as stated by whoever wrote that explanation.  In my answer, the parentheses are surrounding a sequence expression of up to two values:  the evaluation of "foo" and the evaluation of "0". Non-existent values do not end up in the sequence, so that if the <foo> child does not exist, the sequence has only one item, the 0, and so that is returned.  If the <foo> child does exist, it is returned. No concatenation.

Comment: Although the intention of this one liner is not as easy to read as an explicit choose-statement, I like that shorty! Always missed a short if-then-else version for variable assignment. Nice thing is that you can use even additional filters for foo (like text()!='') to check not only existence of foo but also being not an empty value. Nice shortie!

Comment: May I suggest, @jham, that your use of text() is improper? In my teaching of XSLT I counsel stylesheet writers never to address text() nodes in XPath expressions (patterns are fine when you need to test the node, but not in expressions when doing evaluations or tests). This is because not every element with text has only a single text node. Consider: <foo>abc<!--comment-->def</foo> ... there are two text() node children. That can mess things up. I counsel the use of normalize-space() as in (foo[normalize-space(.)],0)[1] ... the function returns a string which evaluates as false() when empty.

Answer (score 11):

### XSLT/XPath 2.0

You can use a [Conditional Expressions (`if…then…else`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-conditionals) on your `@select` expression:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="if (foo) then foo else 0" />
```